# How to add select field in SimpleForm using getter by symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I added getters and setters from symbols like below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  GENDER = { male: 2, female: 1}

  def gender
    GENDER.key(read_attribute(:gender))
  end

  def gender=(g)
    write_attribute(:gender, GENDER[g.to_sym])
  end
end
```

How to add select field for choosing gender? I want to get dynamically options from `GENDER`.

```
= simple_form_for [:member, @member] do |f|
  = f.input :gender
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use collections, see the docs here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections

```
 <%= f.input :gender, collection: User::GENDER.keys %>
```